# Picasso: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp, android-strictmode

While loading image using `Picasso` I'm setting an error reported by `StrictMode`. This happens when I go to a `DetailActivity` view.

```
07-24 15:57:32.346 12190-12199/com.example.flicks E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:62)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.unzip(HttpEngine.java:645)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:443)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:501)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:93)
at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

Here's my **code**. I'm trying to set the Palette color in this code by using the palette library.

```
    Picasso.with(mImage.getContext()).load(Url).into(mImage, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    applyPalette(palette);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```